# Why Fetch Post request with JSON parameter in the body to ASP.NET Core 3.1 WEB API or MVC Controller does not get anything?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, stripe-payments, fetch-api

Trying over a week so far with no success, to find out why I can't get the response from my controller.

1. Note I am not fluent in JS, only C#, but I already have a good understanding of what the fetch does.
2. Now learning ASP.NET Core, but still somewhere under junior level in my overall C# and .Net experience maybe.
3. It is regarding the process of redirecting to Stripe checkout, but fetch and the method as mentioned, can't agree around 200.
4. Originally the controller was a normal MVC controller but among many things tried, I made it also an API controller, hoping something which I apparently don't understand, might fix the issue with its method.
   Turned over the web upside down searching for similar issues, and I have no other options except reaching to you guys, many experienced devs here.
5. The method functions 100%, I mean the logic inside. It returns a session object.
   The API version returns the session; the MVC version returns `this.Json(session);`
   I know that both versions work because I was debugging them by entering inside after a button click
6. Its all happening on localhost, therefore I provided `credentials: 'include'` in the headers... if I am correct.
7. Trying anything with Postman with authorization of course, but no luck so far.
8. Firefox Debugging currently throws no errors when going through the fetch.

The Questions:
 - Does the fetch function properly according to my code?
 - Is the controller prepared to get the payment id from the JSON body of the request?
 - When I hardcode the paymentId inside the controller so that I don't expect any parameter, why this doesn't work as well (the fetch has session undefined)?

Here is the fetch in my Pay.cshtml view

```
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <div id="checkout">
        <form id="payment-form">
            <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-6 py-4 text-center">
                    <button id="checkout-button"
                        value="Pay"
                        class="btn btn-sm btn-labeled btn-primary">
                        <span class="btn-label">
                            <ion-icon name="card-outline"></ion-icon>
                        </span>Pay &nbsp; $ @Model.Amount
                                </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        var stripe = Stripe('@HomyTestPublishableKey');

        var payButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button');

                payButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
                  stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: sessionId
      });
    });

    var sessionId;
    var paymentId = '@Model.Id';

                fetch("/api/payment/createsession/", {
            method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        credentials: 'include',
                  body: JSON.stringify({id: paymentId })
                }).then(function(r) {
                  return r.json();
                }).then(function(response) {
            sessionId = response.id;
      })
          .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
</script>
```

The method in the API Controller looks like this:

```
// Create PaymentSession
[HttpPost]
[Route("createsession")]
public async Task<Session> CreateSession([FromBody]string id)
{
    var userId = this.userManager.GetUserId(this.User);
    var payment = await this.paymentService.GetPaymentDetailsAsync(id, userId);

    var successStringUrl = "https://localhost:44319/Checkout/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}";
    var cancelStringUrl = "https://localhost:44319/Checkout/cancel";

    var options = new SessionCreateOptions
    {
        PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string>
                {
                    "card",
                },

        LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
                {
                    new SessionLineItemOptions
                    {
                        Quantity = 1,
                        Amount = (long)payment.Amount * 100,
                        Currency = CurrencyUSD,

                        Description = $"Payment Id: {payment.Id} for rental at {payment.RentalAddress}",

                        Name = $"Rent Payment for {DateTime.UtcNow.Month} | {DateTime.UtcNow.Year} for rental at {payment.RentalAddress}",
                    },
                },

        PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
        {
            ApplicationFeeAmount = (long)((payment.Amount * 0.01m) * 100),
            CaptureMethod = "manual",

            TransferData = new SessionPaymentIntentTransferDataOptions
            {
                Destination = payment.ToStripeAccountId,
            },
        },

        SuccessUrl = successStringUrl,
        CancelUrl = cancelStringUrl,
    };

    var service = new SessionService();
    Session session = service.Create(options);

    return session;  // the MVC version returns Task<IActionResult> of this.Json(session);
}
```

The options method of Stripe is not important, its only importnat why the fetch can't get anything. and what am I doing fundamentally wrong.
Here is a Stripe engineer CJ Avilla, demonstrating this with PHP and JS but you could get an idea.
After minute mark 20:30 you want to see him creating the fetch and later on, how checkout flow cicks in.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQ5jccnZ2Ow&t=1160s

Will appreciate any suggestions. Throw them to me.

Anyone with serious experience and a little time to dig in, I can provide access to the private github repo (its my first web project and I have to defend it at the end of the ASP.NET Core course at SoftUni).

Thank you!

P.S.
Edit 1:
Added binding model for the Id param, as I was wrongly expecting string but passing json object. However this still does not prove or allow the method to be accessed by the fetch...
Screen-shot added from my browser debugging.
[image: I have several break-points but the one that needs to be hit and is not, is shown by CJ at mark 23:28, this is my code line <code>sessionId = response.id;</code>]

Edit 2:
This code return Status 400 in console

```
fetch("https://localhost:44319/api/payment/createsession", {
            method: 'POST',
            mode: 'same-origin',
            headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            credentials: 'include',
            body: JSON.stringify({ id: paymentId })
            })
            .then(r =>  r.json().then(data => ({status: r.status, body: data})))
            .then(obj => console.log(obj));
```

Comment: Hey Darin :) CJ here... the fetch function does look to be correct assuming @Model.Id is rendered into the paymentId as expected. I'll need to research the controller route here to see if this is how to get the id out of the post body and how to respond with JSON. I'll try to reproduce locally.

Comment: okay, so the trick to getting access to the post data is to create a class that will decompose the arguments passed to your controller. 

I would probably create a class called PayParams or something with one single property with getter and setters for `id`. Then, rather than using `[FromBody] string id` you use `[FromBody] PayParams params` and then `params.id` or whatever to access the ID.

Comment: Hey CJ is that really you, that I wathed you in the video? :)

Comment: Well, I am also in contact with your colleague Franz... but no progress.What I am trying is Stripe Connect payment - collecting payment for one user, sending it to another and keeping a cut as my primitive project is about a long-term rental. So tenant sends money to the owner through my site, therefore its not direct payment, thats why my SessionCreateOptions object is so large. I understand what you mean here, binding model for the parameter. Will try again tomorrow as per your suggestion. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

> why the fetch can't get anything. and what am I doing fundamentally wrong

Your `CreateSession` action accepts a string-type parameter `id`, on your JavaScript client side, you can pass data through request body like below.

```
body: JSON.stringify(paymentId)
```

Besides, if you'd like to make your action can handle `body: JSON.stringify({id: paymentId })` well from client, you can also modify your action to accept a custom model parameter, like below.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("createsession")]
public async Task<Session> CreateSession([FromBody]MyTestModel myTestModel)
{
    var id = myTestModel.id;

    //your code logic here
    //...
```

*MyTestModel class*

```
public class MyTestModel
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @FeiHan. I did as per your second suggestion, the binding model. It doesn't work. Apparently what you suggest and CJ too is the right way to receive the JSON object from the fetch, but I am not reaching the method, otherwise, I would get the proper response. See my screen-shot of the updated question.

Comment: Darin, one other thing to check is that your routes are right, can you share the code for the class definition? I wonder if you need to change your path to /createsession or /api/createsession or some such...

Comment: Please check the status of the request that you sent in browser network tab.

Comment: Hi CJ, here it is in this gist: [link](https://gist.github.com/bodyquest/0e5234a03e54ab30db7274c1e4f9e6d7) All the time I was really wondering is there anything wrong with the routes so tried thousands of things.

Important note, hope it helps:
With Postman two days ago I was able to reach the method with `GET` request and transforming the method with `HttpGet`. However there was `NullReference Exception` at the start line of  `var options = new SessionCreateOptions` (Postman got it). The `paymentId` was hardcoded inside the method so it was not like a missing param was causing that. Why...

Comment: **Edit 2** added in my original post. Console returns `400` on my `fetch()`. Someone should have told me long time ago how exactly to find this out with fetch, compared to regular debugging in Visual Studio. Now one step closer, but still not moving forward :) 

`body: Object { type: "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1", title: "Bad Request", status: 400, … }`

Comment: Hey Darin, I just put this up in case it's useful: https://youtu.be/2-mMOB8MhmE I show how to add general GET / POST routes with .NET Core

Answer (score 0):

```
let serverResponse = await fetch('https://localhost:{port}/api/payment/createsession/',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                mode: 'cors',
                headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({ id: paymentId })
            }
        );
        serverResponse.json().then(function (data) {
            // server response value come to "data" variable
            debugger;
        });
```